Unresolvable issue with Reverb in local ( dockerized )
I am trying (!) to use laravel reverb in my local setup ( dockerized php-fpm nginx mysql )
but not matter what port or host I am keep getting
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8070/app/02f265e93304b96ba8d8?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.3.0&flash=false' failed:  which is bugging me since I am pretty sure about the env variables and tried EVERYTHING ...
here are some of the assumptions you can have in my current situation :
1- Ran reverb:start inside the php-fpm container ( which I am not sure is the best way )
2- set env variables to correct values
3- Haven't setup ssl certificates at all .
4- have echo.js pusher and broadcasting setup already .
Appreciate any thoughts.

Also looking for an answer for this -- but with a ddev container instead

Make sure the WebSocket server is running on a port that Docker has opened up, like port 6001 for Laravel WebSockets.
Then in your .env file set the BROADCAST_DRIVER and PUSHER
configuration.BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=your_app_id
PUSHER_APP_KEY=your_app_key
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=your_app_secret
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

and  in your WebSocket
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT=null
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK=null
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT=6001

Else check in config/broadcasting.php the scheme is set to http since you are running in the local environment  'scheme' => 'http',
Ensure that the WebSocket server and php-fpm can coexist in your Dockerfile, or add the WebSocket server as a separate service in your docker-compose.yml file:
services:
  websockets:
    image: your-websocket-image
    ports:
      - "6001:6001"
    depends_on:
      - app

